# How to control Android app action from android phone google assistant

Tags: android, actions-on-google, voice

I want to perform an action within my android app from google assistant.

For example.
I have an android app with one button, and on click of the button i get a toast saying "hello world".

I want to perform this toast action from google assistant. 
That is:

When my phone is idle, i will say 
"Hello google, display toast from my toast app"
And the toast will be displayed. And after displaying the toast i will get a reply from assistant saying " toast displayed successfully".

How can i achive this ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, what you are looking for is called an [app action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app).

However, app actions are only defined for specific types of apps and Intents, and only particular trigger phrases. You can't define your own phrases at this time.

Comment: Update to this  now we can define custom intents https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/custom-intents#query-patterns